# Как создать конструктор копирования для класса, имеющего члены данных, запрещающие копирование

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

Вообщем вопрос в теме.
Пример:

```
struct A{
    std::mutex mx;
    int copyPosible;

    A() = default;

    template <typename U> //Этот шаблонный параметр необходим
    A(A const & in) : copyPosible (in.copyPosible) {}
};


int main() {
    A a, b(a);

    return 0;
}
```

ошибка компиляции:

> error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
>
> note: ‘A::A(const A&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill formed: struct A{
>
> error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’

С нешаблонным конструктором копирования код компилируется.
Возможно ли создать шаблонный конструктор копирования в таком случае? Если да, то как? Если нет, то почему?

На сколько мне известно, если указан список инициализации, и указаны не всё члены, то те члены, что не указаны, не инициализируются.
Спасибо

Comment: Во-первых, шаблонный конструктор никогда не считается копирующим. Во-вторых, как компилятор должен определить `U` при вызове такого конструктора? Зачем вообще нужен `typename U`?

Comment: 1) Для этого не существует способа. Так? Но а если дополнительным аргументом отправить `U` ?

2) Допустим, мне нужен какой то обработчик внутри тела конструктора, для этого и 
`typename U`

Comment: Какой обработчик?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Обработчик исключения, например.

Comment: Покажите, как вы вызовите именно шаблонный конструктор копирования, pls. Сейчас `mutex` не важен, уберите его, просто покажите, что он (конструктор) будет вызван... Добавьте в его код какой-то вывод, и покажите, что он у вас реально вызывается...

Comment: 1. Можно сделать какой-нибудь `template <typename> struct tag {};`, в качестве второго параметра указать `tag<U>`, и при вызове передавать в него `tag<MyType>{}`. Но это даже близко не будет похоже на копирующий конструктор. 2. Как связан обработчик исключения и шаблонный параметр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что ваш шаблонный конструктор ни фига не вызывается. А вызывается сгенерированный компилятором конструктор - который, понятно, не работает, потому что мьютекс - не копируемый. Вернее, он даже не генерируется, и вызываться нечему...

Когда вы убираете шаблонность - о, тут уже есть *ваш* копирующий конструктор, в котором опять же мьютекс *создается*, но не копируется - вы не сказали компилятору, что его надо копировать, только ваш `copyPosible`. Вот мьютекс и не копируется, и все *выглядит* работающим...

Comment: Вот пример, при котором шаблонный конструктор копирования оказывается допустимым. Объявление: `A(A const & in, U u) : copyPosible (in.copyPosible) {}` Вызов: `A a, b(a,1);`

Comment: @SpaghettiMan Ваш конструктор 1. был без дополнительного параметра. 2.С дополнительным параметром он *не* является конструктором копирования, а просто всего лишь еще одним конструктором с параметрами. Но не копирующим. См. 11.4.4.2. A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&,
volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters
have default arguments. Так что он *обязан* вызываться при `A b(a);`. Вызывайте...